# JasperServer - how to stop horizontal line in report from stretching across screen

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

[image: horizontal lines are stretched across screen]

I created this report in *iReport Professional 4.5.1* and deployed it to *JasperReports Server* today. The total page width is 792 pixels. In my report I have some horizontal lines that are 752 pixels wide. When I run the report in *JR Server* the horizontal lines stretch all the way over to the right side of my monitor. This happens when I schedule the report and ask *JR Server* to save it as an HTML file, but when I schedule the report and save the output as a PDF the lines are the correct size.

How can I keep the horizontal lines from stretching? The stretch type for each line is set to "no stretch." My other report elements are managing to hold their position.

Thanks, 
Lisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Sam! Your answer helped me solve this. My report is a 6-column report and I have labels that I only print in the first column. Cell borders wouldn't work because there would be lots of gaps. However, I realized that my horizontal line did not need to be 752px wide; it only needs to be slightly wider than the width of the first column and the report will take care of copying it into the subsequent columns for me. I set the horizontal lines to 127px wide and now I have an unbroken horizontal line that runs through all of my columns. I can't believe that didn't occur to me when I was creating the report in iReport.

Comment: Also: keep the line at 752px and set it to print in the first column only.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cell borders to draw those lines instead of a static "horizontal lines."